# bootstrap variable grid design layout structure

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

I am new to bootstrap, I am trying to build a bootstrap grid that is similar to the attached image.

I have tried gridster bootstrap (https://github.com/ncthis/gridster-bootstrap) but when I copy the generated html to my html mokeup it can disturb the whole page.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsukvqdjko9qn36/grid.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly wanna follow the design in your DROPBOX, Use **rowspan** and **columnspan** of bootstrap tables.

The trick to create a table with 12 columns similar to **bootstrap grid structure** and place your contents accordingly.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan=6>Grid 1</td>
   <td colspan=6><div>Grid 2</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan=12><div>Grid 3</div></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not bootstrap but gridster does the same and allows a drag and drop (but you can also disable it if the doesn't match with your expectations)
http://fiddle.jshell.net/h9f63/367/

```
good luck
```